# iptables allow dyndns domain name and auto update rules

Tags: iptables

I have registered with dyndns domain for my dynamically changing public ip address to use with iptable rules. On a server I've allowed some ports for this domain in the iptables configuration like the below entries:

```
-A INPUT -s mycompany.dyndns.com -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s mycompany.dyndns.com -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s mycompany.dyndns.com -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

But when ever my modem restarts, I couldn't connect to these allowed ports as public ip changes with modem restart and are not updated in the iptables on the server. Is there any option to automatically update iptable rules on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no, the only way to update an `iptables` rule is to replace it (`iptales -R ...`) or to delete it and add a new one with the updated IP address (`iptables -D ...` followed by `iptables -A ...`).

[This blog post](http://www.len.ro/2007/08/iptables-rule-for-dyndns-host/) discusses the issue and sketches a solution.

Comment: Good answer. Again I've to use script. Ok, how about if use mac address in the iptable rules

Comment: @user3215 MAC addresses stay local to your LAN; they will not travel across internet routers.

Answer (score 0):

> But when ever my modem restarts, I couldn't connect to these allowed ports as public ip >changes with modem restart and are not updated in the iptables on the server.

Even though you are applying rules with a domain name, iptables will resolve to the public IP of given domain at that moment and apply rules with that public IP. 
So with each modem restart or ISP IP lease time expiry, you have to update iptables with the newly allocated public IP.

If you list iptables rules, then it will be confusing as you can see rules that you applied with exact domain name.

```bsh
iptables -L
```

To get clarity, save iptables rules to one file and verify. You can find resolved IP of your domain instead of domain name.

```bsh
iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want in many different ways.
Per instance, dig your Dyndns ip:

```
YOURIP="$(dig yourdomain.ddns.net +short A)"
```

Then use the $YOURIP variable to check your IP regularly and add a firewall rule via a cron command

Dig is a well known utility for querying DNS servers, you can easily install it in your Linux distro should it not be readily available